# Replace punctuation in C++ string

Tags: c++, string, stl

I'm trying to understand why binary_search() doesn't find certain puntuation characters while find() does:

```
array<char, 25> punctuation_chars{'\'', '\"', ',', '.', ';', ':', '+', '*', '-', '_', '?', '!', '=', '|', '^', '/', '\\', '(', ')', '[', ']', '{', '}', '<', '>'};

bool is_punctuation(char c)
{
    auto ret = find(cbegin(punctuation_chars), cend(punctuation_chars), c) != cend(punctuation_chars);
    // auto ret = binary_search(cbegin(punctuation_chars), cend(punctuation_chars), c);
    if (c == ',')
        cout << c << " is" << (ret ? "" : " not") << " punctuation" << endl;
    return ret;
}
```

The commented line doesn't work (for example, for c == ',' returns false), while find returns cend(punctuation_chars)...

Comment: Are you certain that `punctuation_chars` is sorted? You can check by calling `std::is_sorted(punctuation_chars.begin(), punctuation_chars.end())` (it's not: https://wandbox.org/permlink/tpTR98nXBqmSncCY)

Comment: Did you read the documentation for `binary_search`? Do you know what a binary search algorithm is and how it works? Did you look that up?

Comment: You are right, it's just that after few years without C++ I forgot how hard simple things can be. Using javascript for work I'm used to the awesome lodash library, and when I found binary search I just thought "it's a method that takes a container, a search value and returns bool" and didn't ask myself if the container had to be sorted. My bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`punctuation_chars` isn't sorted so `std::binary_search` won't work. You need to call `std::sort`:

```
std::sort(std::begin(punctuation_chars), std::end(punctuation_chars));
```